# Android fragments not saving states, crashing on rotation/screen lock/back

Tags: android, xml, tabs, view

My application is crashing whenever I lock the screen, go back, rotate the screen, or hit the home screen. This application implements a fragment UI with 3 tabs. In my manifest, I have android:configChanges="orientation", and this was working, until I changed something(I don't remember what it was). Now even with that in my manifest, my app can't handle rotation changes. I'm trying to implement onSaveInstanceState, onRestoreInstanceState, onPause, and onResume, but it continues to crash. Here is some of the code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Inflate the layout
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Initialize the TabHost
    this.initializeTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
         // set the tab as per the saved state
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));
    }
    // Initialize ViewPager
    this.initializeViewPager();

}   

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();       
    }

 @Override
protected void onResume() {
super.onResume();         
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("tab",
            mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); // save the tab selected

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("tab");

}
```

LOGCAT for Application launch & crash

Comment: What error message are you getting? Please check with a log-checking application like aLogCat.

Comment: Here is the logcat

http://pastebin.com/dU4663Ey

Answer (score 2):

```
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
outState.putString("tab",
        mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); // save the tab selected
```

should be

```
outState.putString("tab",
        mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag()); // save the tab selected
```

`super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);`

You need to add "tab" to outState before calling onSaveInstanceState in order to avoid an exception when loading it in OnCreate.  In other words, your "tab" is never actually being saved, since you are saving the state before adding "tab" to the state.

Comment: Even if I change that, I still get the same exception. My code actually was this before, I'm not sure why I changed it. Probably just to experiment. But still, I get the same issue with  // Field descriptor #12 I
  public static final int POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE = 1;

Comment: I don't know how, I mean I can find errors, but when the app crashes, in eclipse it opens "FragmentManager.class" and then says "Source Not Found".

Does this help?: http://pastebin.com/MtrFFNBc

Comment: How would I do that? The tutorial I followed for the fragments never mentioned that.